# Using Bean (View Scope) in JSF to show data

Tags: java, jsf

I'm creating an web application, using **JSF (2.0)**.
It has **"ViewProducts.xhtml"** to view Product with page. Each time this page loaded, if parameter has some thing (Eg: **page=1 (ViewProduct.xhtml?page=1)**), it's will automatically set the id to setPage property in that Bean.
But, i'm keeping getting this error:

> Unable to create managed bean **categories**. The following problems were found: - Bean or property class bean.Categories for managed bean categories cannot be found.

Here is my code (Categories act like a product container):

**faces-config.xml:**

```
<faces-config version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/template/header.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>ViewCategories</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/ViewCategories.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>categories</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>bean.Categories</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

**ViewProducts.xhtml**

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"



<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="page" value="#{categories.page}"/>
</f:metadata>

<h:dataTable value="#{categories.listProduct}" var="cus">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value ="#{cus.name}"></h:outputText>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Price</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value ="#{cus.price}"></h:outputText>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Categories.java (ManagedBean)

```
public class Categories implements Serializable {    
    /** Creates a new instance of categories */
    public Categories() {
    }
    private int page = 0;

    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(int page) {
        this.page = page;
    }
    public List<Product> listProduct = null;

    public List<Product> getListProduct() {
        if (listProduct != null) {
            return listProduct;
        } else {
            listProduct = dataAccess.DataAccess.getCategories(this.page);
            return listProduct;
        }
    }

    public void setListProduct(List<Product> listProduct) {
        this.listProduct = listProduct;
    }
}
```

**Stack trace:**

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Unable to create managed bean categories.  The following problems were found:
     - Bean or property class bean.Categories for managed bean categories cannot be found.
     - Bean or property class bean.Categories for managed bean categories cannot be found.
     - Bean or property class bean.Categories for managed bean categories cannot be found.
     - Bean or property class bean.Categories for managed bean categories cannot be found.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:263)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:86)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:69)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:112)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:554)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1248)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:447)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:823)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:937)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1611)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:380)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Please do not put "Solved" in titles. This isn't a discussion forum. Just mark the answer accepted (you already did). Questions with accepted answers show up with a different answer count color in the listing (yellow instead of white). This is sufficient to distinguish "solved problems" from "unsolved problems".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least 3 problems:

1. The bean class `bean.Categories` is not in the classpath.
2. You cannot have a managed property which is of a narrower scope than the managed bean.
3. You're duplicating the managed property with `<f:viewParam>`.

Ensure that the bean class is in the classpath and that you didn't typo'ed the managed bean class. You also need to get rid of the `<managed-property>`, you don't need it if you're already using `<f:viewParam>`.

Not related to the problem, but as you're already on JSF2, I'd also suggest to use annotations instead of the `faces-config.xml`.

Comment: thanks you for answering me so soon.
1. I have a packet, named **bean**. It contains **Categories.java** (a ManagedBean) in Project's root.
3. I removed <managed-property> in config file.
**-> It's still have that prob.**

2. I don't know, can u expand more abt that?
4. I used that file to save the navigation-rule. I searched it using annotation but i can't find anything like that. How can i solve this prob?

Comment: Read the stacktrace once again. Post the bottommost "Caused By" part.

Comment: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Unable to create managed bean categories.  The following problems were found:
     - Bean or property class bean.Categories for managed bean categories cannot be found.at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:263)

Comment: The bottommost one, please. The latest "Caused By" part. That's the root cause. If you don't understand me, edit the entire stacktrace into your question.

Comment: I posted it in my answer. Sorry for not understading your question.

Comment: Is really that the complete stacktrace? I'd expect some root causes. Anyway, how exactly are you developing? With an IDE which automatically builds/deploys the code or just in notepad or something and with manual builds/deploys?

Comment: I copied all the stack i got :(. I'm using NetBean 6.9.1, and TomCat Server 6.0. And i re-posted file config @.@

Comment: Okay. Well, the exception is basically telling that the bean class is not in the classpath. You need to check in the build folder if it's been built into `/WEB-INF/classes/bean/Categories.class`. Also note that Java is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for your help :D. Class Categories it C in UpCase, and it's automatic add by NetBean to config files. I changed its name to categories and it gone x-(.

Comment: I know that but it's hard for a new user to find out the "Accepted Answer" @@ (I try to find that button but i not see it :| ). Thanks u :D